# Are they exactly same? is + verb, is + to + verb, is + verb + ing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1. All you have to do is ask the question.
> 2. All you have to do is to ask the question.
> 3. All you have to do is asking the question.

The first sentence is what I saw on the tv show and the other things I made.

I thought that the first sentence pattern was wrong before.

Do they have exactly the same meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 is grammatically correct, and sounds natural to my (American) ear.

Option #2 is grammatically correct, but does not sound natural to me.  It has the same meaning as Option #1.  It has the same level of formality as Option #1.

Option #3 is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Antonio -- Thank you for the upvote.  I recommend waiting before accepting this answer, though.  Waiting a day or two before accepting an answer encourages other users to post alternative answers.  Those answers might be different, or might be better supported.  Some users use Google n-grams to show how common or how rare various options are.  Other uers might explain why Option #2 sounds less natural, or explain why Option #3 is grammatically incorrect.